# How do I store a ggplot object in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a nested dataset that contains 4 columns: plots (storing ggplot objects), data (the datasets used to make the plots), and x ('a', 'b', 'c') and y ('d', 'e', 'f') (variables that are used in the plots).

The problem is that I'm missing some y variables, so when I try to use a loop to paste them all into a deck, I get an error.

To work around this, I'm making a dataset that does have all combinations of x and y and has an empty plot. That way, the code will run and if the user isn't expecting this, they can go dig deeper.

The problem is that I keep getting an error when I try to put a ggplot object in my dataframe:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `plots = empty_plots`.
✖ `plots` must be a vector, not a `gg/ggplot` object.
```

Why am I getting this when I didn't get it for my nested dataset, and how do I fix this?

Sample data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Test data with all combos of x and y
test_data <- tibble(x = c("a", "b", "c"),
                    y = c('d', "e", "f")) %>%
  expand(x, y)

#Make my empty plot

empty_plots <- ggplot() +
           theme_void() +
           geom_text(aes(0,0,label='You did not have enough data to make this plot. \n If this is unexpected, check code.')) +
           xlab(NULL)

test_data_with_plots <- test_data %>%
  mutate(plots = empty_plots)
```

For the final output, I want a dataframe with 3 columns--x, y, and plots, which contains the empty ggplot object.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be wrapped in a `list` as ggplot objects have list structure - `mutate` expects the length of the column  to be the same as the original data column.  If we check only by the `length` criteria, it is the same as the number of rows of the data

```
> str(empty_plots)
List of 9
 $ data       : list()
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "waiver"
 $ layers     :List of 1
  ..$ :Classes 'LayerInstance', 'Layer', 'ggproto', 'gg' <ggproto object: Class LayerInstance, Layer, gg>
    aes_params: list
...
> length(empty_plots)
[1] 9
```

But, inorder for the ggplot to work, it should be a single block unit instead of splitting into multiple elements.  So we wrap in a list.

```
library(dplyr)
test_data_with_plots <- test_data %>%
   mutate(plots = list(empty_plots))
```

-output

```
> test_data_with_plots
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  x     y     plots 
  <chr> <chr> <list>
1 a     d     <gg>  
2 a     e     <gg>  
3 a     f     <gg>  
4 b     d     <gg>  
5 b     e     <gg>  
6 b     f     <gg>  
7 c     d     <gg>  
8 c     e     <gg>  
9 c     f     <gg>
```

It is possible to make use of the `list` structure to add each element for each row

```
> test_data %>%
    mutate(plots = c(empty_plots))
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  x     y     plots           
  <chr> <chr> <named list>    
1 a     d     <waiver>        
2 a     e     <list [1]>      
3 a     f     <ScalsLst>      
4 b     d     <uneval>        
5 b     e     <theme>         
6 b     f     <CrdCrtsn>      
7 c     d     <FacetNll>      
8 c     e     <env>           
9 c     f     <named list [3]>
```

But, it may not work for later use